# Application Installation Failed - INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, genymotion

Started a new project, and [this](https://gyazo.com/08cf38899348817b28ec2b2978561d92) occurred to me:

I am using `Genymotion` as my emulator. Not sure what causes this problem.

I tried:

- Rebuilding the project
- Made sure I have enough space in my `emulator` (I have 4.5gb left)
- Check if it's already installed in the `emulator`, it hasn't.

Comment: If restarting the emulator and computer doesn't work, just recreate the device.

Comment: I too faced similar issue with Genymotion emulator. I tried with android AVD, it was working fine.

Comment: I am having the same error when trying to run an APK in a Genymotion emulator. It started when I updated Android Studio to 2.3 last night. I suspect it has something to do with the signing of the app with the debug keystore, and it somehow not being compatible with the emulator. What version of Studio and Genymotion are you using? What emulator are you trying to install on, I.e. Nexus 5x 6.0.0?

Comment: Re-creating the device works too!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APK installation failed: \[INSTALL\_FAILED\_VERIFICATION\_FAILURE\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014519/apk-installation-failed-install-failed-verification-failure)

Comment: @MatthewFrancis I tried recreating a new instance of the device, but to no avail. I'm wondering what happened with Android Studio 2.3 that suddenly debug signed apps no longer work in Genymotion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Open terminal, and type `adb shell` to access the emulator shell.

Type `settings put global verifier_verify_adb_installs 0` on the shell.

I think this is related to the recent Google Play Services update. The verifier is more strict. This command in essence disables the **Verify Apps** option. [From this article](https://www.xda-developers.com/psa-play-services-update-broke-titanium-backup-substratum-heres-a-fix/).

Comment: Is this something new with Android Studio 2.3? I'm seeing the same issue with a project that was working before upgrading to 2.3.

Comment: Thanks, @yuku! Could someone elaborate on this?

Comment: I think this is related to the recent Google Play Services update. The verifier is more strict. This command in essence disables the Verify Apps option. Ref: https://www.xda-developers.com/psa-play-services-update-broke-titanium-backup-substratum-heres-a-fix/

Comment: @yuku thanks again. I'd add this link to your answer. It's definitely valuable.

Comment: We are using Castles device and the latest system upgrade set verifier_verify_adb_installs to 1. Thank you @RandySugianto'Yuku'

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Matthew Francis For the solution you need deselect Verify apps from your genymotion or device setting,

**Settings -> Security -> Deselect Verify Apps.**

Now then after try it work,

Answer (score 1):

For Genymotion the following works

> Turning off Google play protect

Please go to Android Emulator **Settings -> Security & Location -> Goolge Play protect** then disable the settings

Answer (score 0):

you have to try to remove the App installed in the emulator manually

Comment: The app isn't installed in the emulator

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting "verifier_verify_adb_installs" to 0 alone is not enough. I need to also set "package_verifier_enable" to 0:

e.g.

```
adb shell

settings put global package_verifier_enable 0
```

Answer (score 0):

in Genymotion emulator please goto Seting > Secureity&Location > google play protect
then off the "scan device for security threads" opetion

Answer (score 0):

In my case, stopping "Google Play Services for Instant Apps" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Genymotion emulators, just turning on the Developer options/USB debugging solved this problem in my case.

[Genymotion: Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718066/genymotion-installation-failed-with-message-install-failed-verification-failure)
 can be referred.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I disable google play protect, google play > play protect > setttings(gear icon) > turn off

Answer (score 0):

Enable this in device settings to allow installation from unknown sources.

`settings -> security -> (Device administration)UnKnown sources`

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by play store

1. open google play store and open drawer
2. click on "Play Protect"
3. click on setting Icon from the top right of your emulator
4. turn off both "Scan Apps with Play Protect" and "Improve harmful app detection"
   5.run your program