# Genymotion: Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE.

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, genymotion

I am running my app on `Genymotion` emulator, but from past `2-3` days it is showing 
`Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.` error.

I don't know what is problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is an explanation of the problem from the Genymotion team  and how to solve it quickly.

One of the steps of the Android application installation is the application verification.
This step is a security feature that prevents applications including malware to be installed.
This step is only activated when Google Play Services are installed.

For safe apps, the application should be installed without any  problem. 
However, since the latest version of Google Play Services, the verifier rejects all application installation, even safe ones.

We are actively working on a solution for this problem. In the meantime, please use the following workaround to disable the verification:

- If not already done, enable the developer settings by clicking several times on Build number in the About phone section of Settings
- Go to the developer settings
- If not already done, enable USB debugging
- Disable verify apps over USB
- Try again to install your application

Answer (score 2):

the same error is fixed by this steep

```
1,Enable Developer settings :
    Open Settings > ( settings of genemotion emulator  or nox ).
    Click 5 times on Build number.
    Navigate to Developer settings.
2 Enable USB debugging.
3 Disable Verify apps over USB.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done. Just turn on USB debugging in developer option in genemotion emulator just like you do in your phone.Removes safety check. It works.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today after I've been doing USB debugging for months.  My issue ended up being the fact that the device was in airplane mode which caused the verification to fail.  When I turned the network on again it worked.

Answer (score 0):

after done all step in Previous post , do this
Genymotion -> Settings -> Security -> check 'Unknown Source'