# blocked by google protect

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Recently I updated to Android Studio 3.2 and the problem I'm facing is that in every single running the app, I get this error.
[image]

[image: Android Studio error]

and when I click ok error says: `Error while Installing APKs`

I clean the project and rebuild again, and it solves the problem. but the dialog from google play protect showing up. I click Instal anyway. and the app will install. but the problem is it happens in every single run. I have to clean, rebuild, accept google play protect and so on.

I know It's duplicate question, but my problem is it's happening over and over and over.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APK installation failed: \[INSTALL\_FAILED\_VERIFICATION\_FAILURE\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014519/apk-installation-failed-install-failed-verification-failure)

Comment: I checked that already, it's not that @SurajVaishnav

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are using an Emulator IF NOT we did not have this issue with a real device

First close the Emulator
If you use this process it will clear all installed apps from the Emulator 
Open AVD manager delete the Emulator or Wipe Data
the BUG people at Android also suggested I delete the SDK and Reinstall
This is a real time waster and we ended up needing to FIX all the Emulators
We can also tell you that Nexus 9 with API 28 is nothing but TROUBLE 5 errors per test