# can no longer run my app says "INSTALLL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE

Tags: android

I can no longer work on my app, when I try to run it I get an error:

> INSTALLL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE"

I tried to uninstall the app, but I still  get the same error

Comment: Any recent Android Studio or SDK update? Anything changed on your system? Or did anything changed on your device? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014519/apk-installation-failed-install-failed-verification-failure

Answer (score 1):

it happened to me once , so i rebooted my device solve my problem